# Impact of updating DynamicRessource inside the transparent background of a WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I have a windows form control inside  wpf application using a windows forms host.

the windows forms control have a transparent background.

The WindowsFormsHost have the background color defined using a DynamicResource.

It's working fine, except when the dynamicresource is updated.
Then the background color of the windows forms control stay the same.

My aim is to fix this. One way could be to catch an event which was telling me the dynamic ressource had change, but i couldn't find such event.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Sounds to me like you implemented the transparent background by simply not painting the background.  Really getting this to work is going to be iffy, search for WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.

Comment: In my mind i set explicitly the background of the winforms control to Color.Transparent.

Comment: Hoq DynamicResource actually updated ? Who updates it?

Comment: I think it's by using a setter, but i can't access in this part of code (third party library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by doing the background binding on the WindowsFormsHost despite the parent panel.